# optimization problem: different conditions to use the $1^{s t}$ order neccessary conditions for a local min to find the candidates for minimizers

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the optimization problem:
$$
\min f(x, y, z)
$$
subject to:
$$
g(x, y, z)=z-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0
$$

Note that $\{g=0\}$ is a cone with vertex at the origin. Also note that
$g$ is not diffferentiable at the origin.

Suppose $f(x, y, z)=a x+c z$ where $a, c \in \mathbb{R} .$

How to use the $1^{s t}$ order neccessary conditions for a local min to find the candidates for minimizers. My thoughts is to consider different cases on the values of $a, c$, but besides $a $ or $ c $ equals zero, is there another condition to consider? After we find the minimizers, how should we solve the optimization problems? I am not familiar with the next procedure. Could anyone give some guidance? Thank you so much!